# Design an O(n) algorithm for find one number not within range [0,n-1]

Tags: arrays, algorithm, integer

An Array A contains `n-1` unique integers in the `range [0,n-1]`, that is , there is one number from this range that is not in `A`. Design an `O(n)` algorithm for finding that number. You are allowed to use only `O(1)` additional space besides the array A itself.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sum up the numbers from from 0 to n-1 and then find the sum of the array and the missing number is sum - sum of array

Explanation: sum if 0+1+2+...+n-1 and the array has all these numbers too except one so when you add to 0+1+2+...+n-1 all the numbers in the array with a "-" prefix, each number will cancel his "+" counterpart and so you will be left with the "+" who has no counterpart in the array and so this is the missing number

**NOTE:** storing a number is log(n) bits but in most places (that I have seen) they dont talk in bit resolution and storing a number is O(1) space, so it depends on how it is defined in your question

Comment: It is noteworthy to mention that adding `n` integers does not take a constant space, but rather a `log(n)` space. The number of bits required for representing the number `n` is `log2(n)`.

Comment: It depends what you consider as space complexity, from what I know storing a number is O(1) but you are right, it depends on how it is defined in the question

Comment: Great. That's the reason you should be careful with this one as an interview question. If you don't take a closer look into it, you might look like a fool if a smart candidate shows up.

Comment: That's a nice answer. I have a little bit of improvement though. The improvement is when the missing number is zero. Your algorithm won't detect it. The solution to this problem is by adding 1 (or call it shifting by 1) to each number in both (the array and the range). Hence, the new algorithm to solve the problem is: `summationOfRange = n(n+1)/2; summationOfArray = n - 1 + sum(array); missingNumber = summationOfRange - summationOfArray - 1;`. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Given lists **a**(size 100) and **b**(size 99) of unique integers in range 0-99 with random ordering.

```
a = RandomSample[Range[0, 99]]
b = Take[RandomSample[Range[0, 99]], 99]
```

Find missing element in **b**.

```
element = Total[a]-Total[b]
```

Language used is Mathematica.